# What is the equivalent to this apt-get when installing PostgreSQL extension for acoustid?

Tags: centos, yum, postgresql

On [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/acoustid/acoustid-server), it says to install the extension using `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.X-acoustid`.
but I'm running on CentOS... when I replace `apt-get` with `yum`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.X-acoustid    
The package isn't found. Error: Nothing to do
```

I'm new to managing linux servers... and I'm not very familiar with yum. Any help is appreciated. Please excuse my ignorance. :)

Comment: Start with a yum search postgresql, I have no idea what repositories or version of centos you are running, but thats a good place to start.